# How do I update my employer, on my Careers profile

Tags: support, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs

[My careers profile](https://careers.stackoverflow.com/cv/edit/89685#) still reflects my old employer.  My account is connected [via LinkedIn](http://linkedin.com/in/newalexandria), but I don't want to "reimport" everything again — which I assume will wipe out what I've added manually.

Clicked 'edit' on my careers profile doesn't show an Employer field.  Where do we do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a new item in the "Experience" section of your CV, and mark it as your current job. Additionally, you can edit your previous job and set its end date. These changes will be reflected to the top of your profile (which currently mentions your old employer).